# Fiware - IDAS: TimeInstant attribute

Tags: fiware, agent, fiware-orion

I’m using the MQTT Ultralight agent. I have seen that when the agent registers into the context broker an entity related to a device, the agent adds to that entity the “TimeInstant” attribute. This attribute seems to be on UTC+0.

I would like to work with UTC +1. I tried modifying the device’s “TimeZone” when registering it, but seems that this doesn’t work, because the time continues to be on UTC+0. Here an example:

```
curl -X POST 172.21.0.23:8090/iot/devices \
-i  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Fiware-Service: red_entrada_4" \
-H "Fiware-ServicePath: /Prueba" \
-d '{
"devices":[
{
    "device_id": "AC_2", 
    "entity_name":"disp_entrada:AC_2",
    "protocol":"PDI-IoTA-MQTT-UltraLight", 
    "entity_type": "disp_entrada", 
    "timezone": "Europe/Madrid" 
}
]}'
```

Is there any way of modifying the default value of the “TimeInstant” attribute, in order to work with a specific UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field was introduced as a future capability and, as it is said in the documentation, it is not in use today. This is the reason why ¡you are not able to change it at present.

Thanks for using IDAS and sorry for our late reply this time!