# Fiware - IDAS UL: TimeInstant attribute

Tags: timezone, fiware, agent

I have the same problem that in this question: [Fiware - IDAS: TimeInstant attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992228/fiware-idas-timeinstant-attribute)

Any news about timeInstant on new features? I didn't find news on Fiware documentation.

Comment: Dear [Fabio Suarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8221901/fabio-suarez), Despite we are working on that, currently this new features it has not been implemented yet. Please, for a nice follow up, could you open an issue like this in the Github site: [Iotagent-NodeLib](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib)? Sorry for the inconvencience, Fernando Méndez.

Comment: If you have "the same problem" as another question, you shouldn't open a new question to ask about it, as this is not helpful. Instead, upvote and possibly favorite _that_ question to show that it's relevant to somebody else and also to be notified about any changes.

Comment: I agree with you Dev-iL, but I can't upvoted it... so it was the only way I found to expose me problem. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 0):

a PR to implement this feature has been just merged as you can see in https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/673.

Could you please update your Ultralight IoT Agent dependencies and check if your issue has been solved?